# Fast token-to-index conversion with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

Let's say I have two large strings of text that I split into words:

```
import numpy as np

s1 = 'this is a test test test'
s2 = 'that is another test'

terms1 = np.array(s1.split())
terms2 = np.array(s2.split())
```

Now `terms1` is `['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'test', 'test']` and `terms2` is `['that', 'is', 'another', 'test']`.

I now want to assign each unique word an ID and then get an array for each `terms`-vector that contains the respective IDs, i.e. the indices into the common "vocabulary" of `terms1` and `terms2`:

```
vocab = np.unique(np.concatenate((terms1, terms2)))
# yields ['a', 'another', 'is', 'test', 'that', 'this']

ind1 = [np.where(t == vocab)[0][0] for t in terms1]
# yields indices into "vocab": [5, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3]
ind2 = [np.where(t == vocab)[0][0] for t in terms2]
# yields indices into "vocab": [4, 2, 1, 3]
```

This basically works. However, the usage of `np.where` in a for-loop seems inefficient and I wonder if there is a better way in NumPy to do such things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `return_inverse` argument of [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), and then split up the returned inverse array using the lengths of the concatenated inputs:

```
In [13]: vocab, inv = np.unique(np.concatenate((terms1, terms2)), return_inverse=True)

In [14]: inv[:len(terms1)]
Out[14]: array([5, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3])

In [15]: inv[len(terms1):]
Out[15]: array([4, 2, 1, 3])
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the `return_inverse` parameter!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `broadcasting` to do all the comparisons at once:

```
In [23]: np.where(terms1[:, None] == vocab)[1]
Out[23]: array([5, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3])

In [24]: np.where(terms2[:, None] == vocab)[1]
Out[24]: array([4, 2, 1, 3])
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage of constructing a potentially very large intermediate object.

Comment: Not as fast and memory efficient as Warren Weckesser's solution, but I also like this approach! I never used broadcasting for comparisons before but it's really powerful in these situations, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you make `vocab` a list, you can use `index()`:

```
vocab_list = list(np.unique(np.concatenate((terms1, terms2))))
ind1 = [vocab_list.index(t) for t in terms1]
```

This seems faster than `np.where()` in my speed tests, but I am not sure what happens for large lists.